# C#, Regex Match pdf directory - add to array of pdf, display only matcheds

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, unity-game-engine

**What I have:**

- Directory with 1000+ documents. Mostly pdfs, but the occasional xlxs or txt.

  1. The pdfs are named: number text.pdf
     (ie, 101 GenericDocument.pdf)
  2. And arranged in "groupings" 100-199, 200-299, etc...
     (These "groupings" are demarcations for different categories)

**What I want:**

- Return an array of fileNames that match my criteria based on category or "grouping"

  1. ie, "122 GenericDoc.pdf", "156 GenericDoc.pdf", etc...
- Display those file names as a list of clickable objects

  1. OnClick, opens the pdf in an external application (its assumed user will have adobe installed)
  2. Once I have an array or list of these documents, I shouldn't have too much trouble assigning them to user-selectable objects, but I figured I'd include that if someone was feeling super generous.

**Errors**

- CS1502, 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguements
- CS1503 Arguement #1, cannot convert 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' expression to stype 'string'

  1. These are both on the line "int number = int.Parse(m.Groups[1]);
- CS0019, Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' and 'string'

  1. This is on the line: "return m.Groups[2] == s;\

**Code**
- Regex Parser

```
public static string matches(int min, int max){
// Matches a number, followed by a space, and then text
Regex r = new Regex("/d+) (.*)&");
string s = ".pdf";
Match m = r.Match(s);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        // Parse number from first match
        int number = int.Parse(m.Groups[1]);

        // If it's outside our range, return empty
        if (number < min | number >= max) 
            return "";

        // Check that the doc type returns only .pdfs
        return m.Groups[2] == s;

    }
    else
        return ""; }
```

**Code**
- Create Doc List

```
public void SetDocList()
{   
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList resultHolder = new ArrayList(); 
    DirectoryInfo directoryPath = new DirectoryInfo(@"pathName");
    ar.AddRange(directoryPath.GetFiles());

    // This variable passed from other script when user selects category
    caseSwitch = selectedDocument;
        Debug.Log("Folder ID: " + caseSwitch);

    switch (caseSwitch)
    {
    // CategoryOne (#s 100 - 199)
        case 0:
        foreach(FileInfo f in ar)
        {
            string result = matches(f.Name, 99, 199); 
            if (result != "")
                resultHolder.Add(result);
            Debug.Log("Doc Name: " + f.Name);
        }
        break;

    // CategoryTwo (#s 200 - 299)
        case 1:
        // Same as above but with range 200 - 299

    // About 8 more Categories with increasing, non-overlapping ranges

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Match.Groups[n]` does not return a string, but a [Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group(v=vs.110).aspx) object. You need to use `Match.Groups[n].Value` to get the string.
2. I think you're missing an *opening bracket* in your first capture group: `"/d+) (.*)&"`

Comment: 1. Ahhh, okay, that makes sense. I'm still trying to get the hang of using Regex. 
2. I have the opening group bracket there in my code, it didn't seem to paste over though.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You're in for a treat. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SrQZq8/1) is a livesaver whenever I need to regex anything. It comes with a reference, an explanation on each of your tokens, and the captured results.